# How does this pseudo code is false (does not output 43)

Tags: pseudocode

I am studying Software System Development A-Level with Cea. The code is displayed below. The mark scheme says that the pseudo code is false, can someone please explain why that is?

Pseudo Code:

```
The output from the following pseudo code is 43.
(method) – void incrementNum( int numParam ){
 numParam++
}
(main method) – void main(){
int numArg = 42
incrementNum( numArg )
output numArg // writes 43
}
```

Comment: Please put the code into you question, linked images can get lost and are not indexed for others. Apart from that, it would be great if you put at least as much effort into the question as the person who is answering.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into function evaluation strategies, in particular [Call by Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value). The function `incrementNum` receives a copy of `numArg` called `numParam`, which is increased. The original variable is untouched. Depending on the actual programming language, you have multiple solutions:

- rewrite incrementNum such that it returns its argument (see [cybermonkey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43843607/1109583))
- use a different evaluation strategy. e.g. in C++ you can call by reference (note the `int&` vs `int` in the signature of increase):

```
#include <iostream>

void increase(int& v) {
  v++;
}

int main() {
  int i = 42;
  increase(i);
  std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

outputs 43.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with this code:

- `numParam` isn't assigned to from `incrementNum`, meaning that it
  won't affect the value of `numParam` and so won't increase the value
  to `43`
- `incrementNum` doesn't return (and won't since it's a `void`- it should be an `int`).

Code that *will* work is as follows:

```
int incrementNum(int numParam){
    return numParam + 1;
}

void main() {
    int numArg = 42;
    numArg = incrementNum(numArg);
    output numArg; //Writes '43'.
}
```

Comment: I think for it to work you also have to change the function to return ++numParam;

Comment: @DevNewb Pseudo-code is pseudo-code for a reason; it's rough code that is language-independent. `++numParam` and `numParam++` are pretty much universally understood as 'add 1 to the variable', and is something I intentionally didn't do properly as I didn't want to complete their homework in its entirety.

Comment: What about changing it to ```numParam = numParam +1; return numParam;``` respective ```return numParam + 1``` then? For beginner questions like this, this level of detail should go into the pseudo code.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Pseudo-code should not be functional code (to the extent that you can copy & paste into a compiler and be done with it); you didn't post pseudo-code.

Comment: There is no programming language, where return numParam++ actually returns numParam+1, your use of this programming construct is highly misleading. By the way, the only non-compiling code in your answer is not related to the original problem.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x It's pseudo code, it's NOT supposed to be able to work by copying & pasting into an IDE, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to renew a 6 months old discussion. Can we agree to disagree on the use of the ```++``` operator in pseudo-code?

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Let's agree to disagree :-).

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Reviewing my old answers, you win ;-).

Comment: I didn't expect that :-) I still think it was an interesting discussion beause pseudo code is such a loosely defined construct that confuses students a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the method incrementNum isn't returned to the numArg and the argument isn't passed by reference (e.g. for c). So the value of numArg is still 42 after the method call.